# Where to put the hypen (if any) in "status quo oriented"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

Writing the following sentence,

> During the negotiation of both regulations, bargaining
>   power was distributed in favour of the status quo oriented states.

I wonder where to put a hyphen, if any? Status-quo oriented, status-quo-oriented, status quo-oriented?

Does a rule exist for such examples or is the placing of a hyphen here left to the taste of the writer?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/251135/55623) to a related question, as well as the canonical question that's marked as a duplicate of.  In brief: the most specific and technical typographic advice is to use the en-dash (not hyphen) to separate "oriented" from "status quo" (which itself will have no joining characters, neither hyphen nor dash): "status quo–oriented".

Comment: ...though the above is by no means the 'only correct answer'; essentially, it's a recommendation. The overriding necessity is to avoid confusion (brown bear-like animal or brown-bear-like animal). As for the en-dash versus hyphen debate, it becomes senseless when one realises that variation with font used can render disambiguation ridiculously involved.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I specifically avoid (and sometimes disparage) fonts without clear distinction between hyphen, en dash, and em dash. It's unfortunate that typographers aren't always aware of the application of their art.

Comment: @nomad Typography is off-topic on ELU. And what you say is personal opinion. There are even some people who can still use a pen; are we now going to legislate as to whose en-dashes must be considered incorrect?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fortunately, we're talking about typography only as it relates to a grammatical function, so we're 100% on topic here! And lucky, because you're the one who brought up the topic of fonts in the first place. :)

Comment: You're saying that 'Typography is off-topic' is inherently inadmissible? Not the spirit of the law, but 'Recommendations as to which [imagine I'm not using the word] fonts etc should be used' are off-topic. And 'which punctuation styles amongst various choices presented by different style guides should be used' is similarly primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good thing I didn't recommend any fonts. I simply agreed with you—that variation in fonts *can* render disambiguation difficult—by saying some fonts do and some fonts don't. I've never seen someone argue so vehemently against someone who agreed with him from the beginning—and for breaking a rule that, if it was broken, he broke first and just as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check out [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/251135/55623) to a related question, as well as the canonical question that's marked as a duplicate of. In brief: the most specific and technical typographic advice is to use the en-dash (not hyphen) to separate "oriented" from "status quo" (which itself will have no joining characters, neither hyphen nor dash): "status quo–oriented". – Dan Bron
>
> ...though the above is by no means the 'only correct answer'; essentially, it's a recommendation. The overriding necessity is to avoid confusion (brown bear-like animal or brown-bear-like animal). As for the en-dash versus hyphen debate, it becomes senseless when one realises that variation with font used can render disambiguation ridiculously involved. – Edwin Ashworth